# Jenkins - How to just trigger action when push happens to Bitbucket repository?

Tags: jenkins

I have connected **Bitbucket** to my **Jenkins** on vps  (where I have **BitBucket plugin** to trigger events when changes are pushed/commited to Bitbucket).

So when Push happens on BitBucket repository, Jenkins starts build (that takes about 10 seconds). After that, the `Post-build` event happens, where I use specific command (*sending changed files to somwhere*).  However, I am only interested to run that specific command, and I don't need building at all (so I could save 10 seconds).

Any way to do that?

p.s. Here is what config I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET3Hx.png

Comment: Are you using jenkins 2 (jenkins file) in your repository. please share mire details on your current pipeline code.

Comment: @T.Todua unchek build when change is pushed to repository (Build-trigger section) (no build will run)

Comment: if you uncheck build I don’t think the job will run.

Comment: @RavishankarSivasubramaniam and that's what i ask. Is there any way just to trigger specific action/command when something changes in Repository... without building..

Comment: @ShivendraGupta when unchecked, it doesnt run at all.

Comment: Remove ssh publisher step. add a free form build command step and run command from there

Comment: @T.Todua Click on Add Build Step and select Execute Shell

Answer (score 1):

Based in the screenshot the Jenkins job does the following

1. Triggered on Source code change
2. Runs the build step ( which runs ssh publisher plugin)
3. Post build

If you just want to run the command you have in post build. Remove the ssh publisher step. Add a new build step that executes command/shell and add your current post build command in the step.

[image: Add Build]